Using Mocha to run unit test for Node.js not working as expected
I am using mocha to run a unit test on my Node.js server code which inserts a user address, reads it and validates data and then deletes the address.
it('Create User Address', function(done) {
    var userId = 'testID';
    var address = '123 Test Cres';
    var city = 'Toronto';
    var region = 'Ontario';
    var country = 'Canada';
    var startDate = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    var responseWrite = {};
    var responseRead = {};
    request('http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/createUserProfile' + '?userId=' + userId + '&address='
            + address + '&city=' + city + '&region=' + region + '&country=' + country + '&startDate=' + startDate, async function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("Getting response after write");
        responseWrite = await JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(responseWrite);
        expect(responseWrite.userProfile.userId).to.equal(userId);

        request('http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/getUserProfile' + '?id=' + responseWrite.userProfile.id, async function(error, response, body) {
                console.log("Getting response id after write!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                console.log(responseWrite);
                responseRead = await JSON.parse(body);
                console.log("Getting response id after READ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                console.log(responseRead.userProfile);
                expect(responseRead.userProfile.userId).to.equal(userId);
                expect(responseRead.address).to.equal(address);
                expect(responseRead.city).to.equal(city);
                expect(responseRead.region).to.equal(region);
                expect(responseRead.country).to.equal(country);
                //console.log(responseRead.startDate);

            });
         done();
    });


    // tear down delete user profile created for test
    after(function () {
        request.delete({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/deleteUserProfile',
                 form: {id: responseWrite.userProfile.id}}, async function(err,httpResponse,body){
                 console.log("DELETEING PROFILE" + responseWrite.userProfile.id);
                 console.log(body);
                 responseDelete = await JSON.parse(body);
                 expect(responseDelete.userProfileStatus).to.equal(200);
                 //done();

         });
      });


});

This code works however it doesn't seem to execute the expect assertations on the profile address (userId, address, city, region, country). So if I change the userId to "THROW ERROR" it throws an unexpected error.
expect(responseWrite.userProfile.userId).to.equal("THROW ERROR");

The error is based on a timeout which is thrown when I ran the unit tests:
 1) Create User Address:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/Projects/CloudMedic/test/test-user.js)

I run the tests using at 10000ms timeout.
npm test
Any idea on what is causing this weird behaviour? Thanks for your help.

Don't use callbacks (done), as this leads to flaky control flow.All up-to-date test frameworks including Mocha support promises, especially since you already mix them. Also this is not a unit test, in case this was the intention

Thank you, I was able to answer my question by using promises instead of the done callback. Just for best coding practices why this is not a unit test? I wanted to run a test to create a user profile - address - read it and then delete it from my database. ie. Testing CRUD functionality.

Nested thens is an antipattern because this creates room for errors. await only would be cleaner. Any way, it looks workable in its current state. You test multiple units at once, it's functional/integration/e2e test, depending on the terminology in use and the point of view. A unit test would be fast and test server controllers/middlewares with db being mocked

I moved away from the callback using done. Instead of using the request library I am now using the node.js fetch command and promises. Here is the code that now works for me:
it('Create User Address', async function() {
    var userId = 'zcU7Q09GwsdvtKrLaR8M';
    var address = '123 Test';
    var city = 'Toronto';
    var region = 'Ontario';
    var country = 'Canada';
    var startDate = new Date().getTime();
    var responseWrite = {};
    var responseRead = {};
    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/createUserProfile' + '?userId=' + userId + '&address='
            + address + '&city=' + city + '&region=' + region + '&country=' + country + '&startDate=' + startDate, {
            method: "GET"
            }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(async response => {
                console.log("Getting response after write");
                responseWrite = response;
                console.log(responseWrite.userProfile.id);
                expect(responseWrite.userProfile.userId).to.equal(userId);

                await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/getUserProfile' + '?id=' + responseWrite.userProfile.id, {
                        method: "GET"
                        }).then(response => response.json())
                           .then(response => {
                            responseRead = response;
                            console.log("Getting response id after READ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                            console.log(responseRead.userProfile);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.userId).to.equal(userId);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.address).to.equal(address);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.city).to.equal(city);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.region).to.equal(region);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.country).to.equal(country);
                            expect(responseRead.userProfile.startDate._seconds).to.equal(Math.trunc(startDate/1000));
                    });
            });

    // tear down delete user profile created for test
   after(async function () {
        await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/deleteUserProfile',
                { method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ id: responseWrite.userProfile.id})
             }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(response => {
                 responseDelete = response;
                 expect(responseDelete.userProfileStatus).to.equal(200);

            });
      });

 

